# How to enable tooltip in Kendo UI Grid if cell has ellipsis?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to check whether the cell of a Kendo Grid contains an ellipsis on resize so it will show a tooltip? The ellipsis is declared via CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use this function on elements that have text-overflow:ellipsis property

```
function isEllipsisActive(e) {
     return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/cgzW8/115/

Comment: You show how check ellipsis on simple span element, not Kendo Grid, and tooltip not showing in your example.